# How to get email from Microsoft graph api oidc/userinfo endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-oauth

I have setup oauth via azure, i have received an authorization_code which i have exchanged for an access_token. I am then attempting to use that access token to get userinfo data including the email as described in the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo). However in the response it does not return to me the email.

```
{
    "sub": "<redacted>",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "family_name": "John",
    "given_name": "Doe",
    "picture": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value"
}
```

The documentation suggests that in order for email to be returned in the response it requires the email scope. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo#userinfo-response

However i believe i am already specifying that i want the email scope.

**App Permissions**

[image]

**/oauth2/v2.0/token** (the scope shows profile, openid, email and user.Read)

[image]

What am i missing?>

Comment: Please check whether the user's profile has **`email`** exists or not **[here](https://i.imgur.com/s7pO6r7.png)**

Comment: Good spot the test user i was using does not have an email set

Comment: cant test if adding it, fixes my problem though beuase im uanble to edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

I created one Azure AD application and added **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now I generated the `access token` with **same scope** as you like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:app_id
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
client_secret:secret
code:code
redirect_uri:redirect_uri
```

**Response:**

[image]

I used the above token to get **user info** data and got response ***without email*** like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
```

**Response:**

[image]

This is because the **email** field in user's profile is not set.  So, I updated **email** field by editing user's properties.

Now I generated access token again and used it to get **user info** data and got response ***with email*** like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
```

**Response:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the AzureAD `userinfo` endpoint to give me the user's email, even though the scope is defined in the original `/authorize` request, and there's also the email API permission in the Azure portal.

What worked for me is retrieving this information from the id_token. In the request to `/oauth2/v2.0/token`, which is done before, not only an access token is retrieved, but also an id_token, and within it's payload is the email of the user along with more information. Even Microsoft seems to suggest doing this here, in the "Consider using an ID token instead" section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo#userinfo-response